# Not able to install latest mercurial release on fedora

Tags: fedora, mercurial

I am trying to install latest mercurial on fedora by doing sudo yum install mercurial .

But doing so I am getting mercurial 1.1 that is not latest release .Current mercurial release is 1.6+ .

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're running a somewhat older version of fedora, since

```
hg --version
```

as well as

```
yum info mercurial
```

on Fedora 13 give me 1.6.4 .

So you can either upgrade your fedora to a newer version, or install mercurial through pypi:

```
sudo easy_install mercurial
```

or rather

```
sudo pip mercurial
```

since pip also allows to uninstall. easy_install is part of python-setuptools